# Best way to write Integration test in spring webflux

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I don’t want spring to auto wire web client test. I got my application running on opeshift.  Spring boot test is not working properly unless it finds a @spring boot configuration in the same module. I am having a different module for integration test.

Documentation not clear enough to tell difference between webfluxtest vs springboottest

Comment: Can you tell us what you want to test? Springboottest generally loads up a spring application, while webflux test doesn't look for components service etc

Comment: I wanted to write Junit test but look like as of now we can't mock WebClient. That is still under development.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want to have Integration Tests based on Spring WebFlux without the Spring Context of your application being initialized by the tests.

If that's the case, you can achieve this using `WebTestClient`.

> The client for testing can be bound to real server or work with specific
>   controllers or functions.

In your IntegrationTest file, you can build the client and tests the expected output like this :

```
@Test
public void testWebTestClientWithServerURL() {
    WebTestClient.bindToServer()
        .baseUrl("http://localhost:" + port)
        .build()
        .get()
        .uri("/resource")
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus()
        .isOk()
        .expectBody();
}
```

Based on that link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient

Going into details : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/WebTestClient.html#bindToServer-org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpConnector-

Answer (score 0):

This how I do the tests against webflux app without SpringBoot in classpath:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [AppConfig::class])
class WebApiTest {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var context: ApplicationContext

    lateinit var testClient: WebTestClient
    lateinit var client: WebClient

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        testClient = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context).build()
        client = WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(HttpHandlerConnector(WebHttpHandlerBuilder.applicationContext(context).build()))
                .build()
    }
}
```

Code is written in Kotlin, but probably everyone have an idea how to rewrite it in Java.